# Synthetic bean not detected in bean archive due to being added to WeldDeployment.additionalClasses archive

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans, synthetic, weld-se

I've been playing with Weld and CDI for a few months now and I've recently come across the following issue.

**Problem situation**

- Using Weld SE 3.1.5.Final
- Created a CDI Extension which adds a bean (`SomeBean`) using `@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery abd`
- `SomeBean` is a custom bean that has `ArrayList.class` as Class and returns 1 qualifier (`@CustomQualifier`).
- A different bean (`DifferentBean`) then declares a `@Inject @CustomQualifier ArrayList<String> variableName;`
- This injection point fails due to `Unsatisfied dependencies`.

**Investigation**

From the Bean Validation Report I've been able to determine that:

- Weld creates 2 Bean Archives

  1. With:

     - Identifier: MyProject\build\classes\java\main
     - Type: All
     - Beans.xml: Version not defined.
  2. With:

     - Identifier: org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.WeldDeployment.additionalClasses
     - Type: Annotated
     - Beans.xml: No beans.xml
- The CDI Extension is a bean located in Archive 1.
- The result of the `DifferentBean` instantiation is located in Archive 1.

  - This bean has:

    - Kind: MANAGED
    - Class: `my.package.DifferentBean`
    - Qualifiers: `@Default`
    - Scope: `@Dependent`
- The result of the `SomeBean` instantiation is located in Archive 2.

  - This bean has:

    - Kind: SYNTHETIC
    - Class: j.u.ArrayList
    - Qualifiers: `@CustomQualifier`
    - Scope: `@ApplicationScoped`

**Cause**

Based on this I'm presuming that for some reason the `SomeBean` my custom Extension is adding is being added to archive 2 and therefore not accessible from archive 1 where `DifferentBean` is located.

If that assessment is correct, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the issue.
I was expecting Weld to resolve the generic for the ArrayList.class to ArrayList. This did not occur, after removing the generic my problem was resolved.